# In which QED limit are Einstein's rate equations for transitions in atoms valid?

Tags: atomic-physics, laser, quantum-optics

I guess one has to assume low intensities? What are notable differences in a full quantum treatment?

I'm familiar with the semi-classical theory of atomic transitions (coupling classical field to quantized atom), but don't know anything about quantization of the EM field. I'm mostly interested in the consequences, no exhaustive calculations are needed. I only found confusing literature, which is beyond my scope for now.

Comment: I will not attempt to answer this question, but leave some hints for finding literature: The applicability of rate equations is the subject of laser theory. They can in essence be derived from fully quantum Maxwell-Bloch equations in certain limits. There is a vast amount of literature on this topic. In my opinion the clearest account can be found in *H. Haken, “The semiclassical and quantum theory of the laser”, in S. M. Kay, A. Maitland, editors, “Quantum Optics”, 201, Academic Press, New York (1970)*

Answer (score 0):

Einstein's argument is that in thermal equilibrium, there must be detailed balance between stimulated emission, stimulated absorption, and spontaneous emission. So long as these are the only processes describing interactions between light and the material of interest, detailed balance **must** hold in equilibrium.

I suppose if you look at frequencies of light away from absorption lines the detailed balance argument becomes vacuous (ie, stimulated emission and absorption will vanish). And, I suppose if you look at very high frequency light (gamma rays) you may have to worry about exciting nuclear states.

But otherwise this argument is extremely powerful and will always work so long as you are balancing these three processes.

"... if your theory is found to be against the second law of thermodynamics I can give you no hope; there is nothing for it but to collapse in deepest humiliation." - [Arthur Eddington](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Arthur_Eddington)

Comment: I think that this answer is besides the point. Independently of thermodynamic arguments, the rate equation picture itself breaks down for truly quantum systems. Therefore detailed balance in the sense of the Einstein equations is not necessarily a given since the equations themselves can be incomplete in the first place.

Comment: Hm. I'll admit to not being an expert on lasers, but I'm a little surprised by this response. The premise of using the Einstein rate equations is that you are in some kind of thermal equilibrium. Even if you are in a system with a small number of photons, there is surely some detailed balance requirement that transition probabilities between stimulated emission (eg by incoming photons), stimulated emission, and spontaneous emission must balance. Unless other states are available, or unless there is a net flow of photons out of the system (which would then not be in equilibrium).

Comment: I always understood the point of the argument to be the fact that *it is possible* to create a macroscopic system containing light and atoms in thermal equilibrium, implies relationships among quantum mechanical transition probabilities. It is like an argument from unitarity.

Comment: Let's look at an example where rate equations break down: resonance fluorescence of a two-level atom. While you have no more than two states contributing, it is important to take into account the coherences between them. This is not included in rate equations, where only populations are accounted for.
With regards to your last point: I sort of agree and I'm not saying your answer is wrong as such, probably you can set up some generalized quantum version of detailed balance. But I think this shows why the answer is besides the point: it does not really address the limitations of rate equations

Comment: Yes Wolpertinger is perfectly right. I will skim through your reference @Wolpertinger the next few days, if I don't make progress there I will put a big bounty on the question. But I think the text covers the limiting process somewhat.

Comment: @Wolpertinger Thanks for clarifying, that is very interesting and I hadn't appreciated this point before.

Comment: I suppose the point is, roughly, there is a difference between incoherent vs coherent superpositions.